# Designing a graph like DB

Tags: database-design

In my case, I have 5 directions: `1:North, 2:South, 3:East, 4:West, 0:Unknown`. A user can stand in one direction of another user. If he is not standing in any direction, he will be considered in the unknown direction.

```
A, B, north
A, C, north
A, D, north
A, E, south
A, F, south
A, G, south
B, A, south
B, C, south
B, K, east
```

In the above table, B, C, D are standing in north direction of A and E, F, G are standing in direction south of A and so on.

Expected operation frequency:

- I expect hardly 10 updates in a month for a user
- I expect max 1000 (300 in general) entries against a user in bulk.
- I expect hardly 15 insertions against a user in a month
- I expect hardly 10 deletions in a month against a user

Another way I can think to design the DB for the above situation

```
A, B, 1, 2
A, C, 1
A, D, 1
A, E, 2
A, F, 2
A, G, 2
B, C, 2
B, K, 3
```

or

```
A, 1, [B,C,D]
A, 2, [E,F,G]
B, 2, [A, C]
B, 3, [K]
```

But this design will make the find, and update operations a bit complex. How should I design the DB for the above situation?

**Update**

I'm trying to create a DB for a social website.

- I'm expecting more than 1 million users in the next 2 years.
- There would be around 2000 find queries against a user in a month.

Answer (score 1):

If your primary concern is with the graph of user connections, then use a graph database. There are [many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) out there. Some are graph-processing engines are built on top of existing NoSQL or relational products.

These products are specifically optimized for the friend-of-friend type of queries typical for social networks. The schema definition and queries are typically much simpler than the same rules implemented on a relational engine.